# How do I autofill a formula across a row using a shortcut?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking to accomplish the same thing that happens when you double-click the bottom right corner of the autofill box, but instead of it filling the content down the column, I want it to fill across a row. This means, it should be able to update relative references accordingly as well as recognizing the end of my data.

Are there any shortcuts to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, but there seems to be no built in feature for doing this, in a similar fashion.

Your options are:
**For formulas or series**
Drag from the corner instead of double-clicking.

**For formulas**
*Using fill*
Select the first cell, extend selection to the end with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT</kbd>,
then fill with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

*Using copy/paste*
Select the first cell, copy with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, extend selection to the end with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT</kbd>, then paste with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

**For seires**
Select the first cell, extend selection to the end with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT</kbd>,
then use the fill menu and select series and press OK.
[image]

**Optionally, you could write the function as a macro**
And call it with a custom shortcut.
In the developer tab, record a macro and give it a proper name and shortcut.
Stop the recording, and edit the macro to the following:

```
Sub Fill()

    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, Selection.End(xlToRight).Address), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

Then instead of double-clicking the corner, you use the shortcut to fill the row instead.